# Magento 1 get quote id of current user

Tags: php, cart, magento-enterprise, quote, magento-1.14

I've gone through a number of questions on here relating to retrieving the current quote for the current browsing user, but each one yields the same result:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
```

Both give me a quote that has an entity_id of one less than the actual quote I'm looking for.

I can see the correct quote in the db as, let's say id #100002, but this returns id #100001.

I know that this is not the correct quote because running getCouponCode() returns null and I can see that is because the entity_id that is returned doesn't have one set, but the actual cart does have a coupon code and so does the entity_id that follows next.

Comment: You are doing it correctly, if you are using it in local or staging, then Truncate sessions and try again with the same criteria

Comment: I've been backtracking and can't seem to figure out how the cart is getting its session that my code is not. It runs the same function that I am to get the quote only it returns the correct object and mine returns essentially a blank quote.

Comment: Have you tried clearing session and try again?

Comment: Yes, I've tried logged in, not logged in, clearing the session, incognito window but they all yield the same result